# Can I avoid phishing messages using sender ID to fool me?

Tags: iphone, messages, security

I've just received a phishing message on my iPhone that uses a fake sender ID of "Qantas". The message appears alongside legitimate messages coming from Qantas.

The scam is described by Qantas [on their website](https://www.qantas.com/au/en/support/contact-us/scam-assistance.html#mystery-box-prize), and on [this unofficial forum](https://www.australianfrequentflyer.com.au/community/threads/qantas-mystery-box.91328/). The Qantas information mentions sender ID:

> Unfortunately scammers can change sender ID names which makes it confusing for the recipient to recognise when a legitimate message has been sent and when it is a scam. These messages – because of the sender ID name – can then be grouped with genuine messages with Qantas.

Is there anything I can do to minimise the risk of phishing, such as displaying the phone number the message is coming from? I tried clicking on "info", but it doesn't display any phone numbers, either for the phisher or the legitimate sender.